# Check if string contains an underscore in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm was wondering of a lightweight way of finding if a string contains an underscore (_).
As a bonus if it was possible to have an if statement that not only checks for an underscore checks if the string is only **two words** connected.

**E.g** I'm looking to check for strings like this "foo_bar".

With no spaces, just the two words and an underscore.

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Comment: There is a section in the PHP Manual called **[String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)**. Get a start with `strpos`. For the bonus there is `substr_count`.

Comment: Going through your previous questions I cannot but notice that there is lots of questions that are easily answered by searching the PHP Manual or Google or Stack Overflow. You are encouraged to do some research before asking new questions here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: @hakre According to its question he needs something more intelligent. He needs to test if the strings is made of two words separated by underscore. I think it's a good question.

Comment: @Karolis: The string representation of a *word* remains nearly undefined, the only thing that can be specifically said is that a word is everything not containing an underscore and is one code-point at least. Next to that I didn't vote for closing the question but suggested to give a link to a really useful PHP language resource. Next to that there are tons of similar questions here on SO as well as uncountable howtos out there in the net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = 'foo_bar';
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$/i', $str)) {
    // contains an underscore and is two words
} else {
    // does not contain two words, or an underscore
}
```

Comment: `preg_match('/.+_.+/','foo__') == 1`

Comment: Better now, although I don't think `%!^_#*$` would be a valid word ;P

Comment: @Mchl: Well, that's up to the OP to specify exactly what chars it will contain. However, I think we finally got there now, didn't we?

Comment: Better again :) How about `lorem ipsum foo_bar` ?

Comment: @Mchl: This one came with no surprises, I was undergoing edit! Thanks for your efforts. :)

Comment: You could also add `i` flag to make it case insensitive and leave just `[a-z]` class.

Comment: This answer esssentially turned into Mchl's answer with Shef's name on it.

Comment: @Chase: I can let Mchl copy it and I will delete mine, if that would make you happy. Mchl helped me understand where my regex would fail, and added a few ideas, for that I thank him. I continuously add to others' answers, I don't think that makes them mine though. Besdies, regex is just regex there is not much ways you can go around it.

Comment: It's not like I'm envious or something :P As long as the answer that is correct is on top, I'm fine ;) Although I must say IMHO Karolis' answer is the best one.

Comment: @Shef I apologize. I didn't mean to offend you. Please, pardon my dry humor. Ultimately, you have the right answer, and that is what matters. :)

Answer (score 7):

Example: `preg_match('/^[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+$/', $string);`

Comment: I like this one, the best so far I think

Comment: Definitely the best one. Inside the character classes for easier readibility and less confusion a lower case `w` is used, usually. There is no need to add the underscore inside the character class, `\w` includes it. The correct regex would be `^[\w]+_[\w]+$`.

Comment: @Shef Nope. Your regex will also match `aaa_bbb_ccc` :)

Comment: `^[\w]+_[\w]+$` matches `___` however, while `^[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+` does not.

Comment: +1 Since I don't like handing out -1's. Had to find another answer I liked to balance my karma :)

Comment: @Ivar Actually you don't have to :)

Comment: Hi, its not working for "sometext_%", please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

```
    $mystring = "hello_there";
    $pos = strpos($mystring, '_');

    if(false !== $pos) {
        //no _ in the mystring
    }
    else {
        echo "_ found at pos ".$pos; 
    }
    //in this example else part will execute
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:
`preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z1-9]+_[a-zA-Z1-9]+$#','foo_bar');`

See [here for some really good tutorial on what all that means.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Could you place that in an if/else statement?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

You could also do something like:

```
count( array_filter( explode( '_', str_replace( " ", "_", "foo_bar" ) ) ) ) // == 2
```

Comment: `count(explode('_','_')); // ==2`

Comment: Not really: `count( array_filter( explode( '_', "lorem ipsum  _ foo bar" ) ) ) //==2`

Comment: Well then, added a str_replace( " ", "_" ) ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(str_replace("_", "", $x) != $x) {
    // There is an underscore
}
```