# Check if string contains two word or special character with underscore between in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if the string contains an underscore in two words and also can be special characters:

What I'm doing is:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$/i', $value)
```

Case worked:

```
mytext_second
```

Case not worked:

```
sometext_%
```

I was following this question but didn't work for me:
[Check if the string contains an underscore in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821679/check-if-string-contains-an-underscore-in-php)

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add special characters in your regular expression, for example:

```
$value = 'mytext_%';
preg_match('/^[a-z$&+,:;=?@#|\'<>.^*()%!-]+_[a-z$&+,:;=?@#|\'<>.^*()%!-]+$/i', $value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Include all characters you want to allow in a character class, not just letters. You may use

```
^([a-z%]+)_(?1)$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6HqoAJ/3)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(` - 1st capture group.

  - `[a-z%]+` - Match at least one character from the defined character class.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `_` - Match a literal underscore.
- `(?1)` - Recurse the 1st subpattern.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "special characters" to the character classes. You currently only allow characters `a-z` (and `A-Z` because of the `i` modifier).

To allow the `%` it would be:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z%]+_[a-z%]+$/i', $value)
```

You can read more about character classes here, https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. Two characters to watch out for are `]` and `-` in them. These characters should be escaped to be literal (the `-` creates ranges and the `]` would close the character class).

You can add any individual character to a character class. You can't group characters in a character class, e.g. `[the]` allows a `t`, `h`, or `e` not the word. `[(the)]` also wouldn't allow the word, it would allow `()`s as well.

If "special characters" are print ascii characters you could do:

```
preg_match('/^[!-~]+_[!-~]+$/', $value);
```

or

```
preg_match('/^[[:print:]]+_[[:print:]]+$/', $value);
```

Comment: Thanks, What if there is any other special character instead of "%".
there can also "$", etc.

Comment: You need to add any/all special characters to the character classes. A character class is the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
$str = 'sometext_%demo';
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+[_!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>][a-z]+$/i', $str)) {
    // contains an underscore or with special character
} else {
    // does not contain underscore or with special character
}
```

this will return `true` for the `sometext_%demo` example.